# Parse XML to Table Where Value May Not Exist

Tags: php, arrays, xml-parsing

I am trying to figure out a way to parse the data in an XML file to a table. The problem is that if the ChargeType isn't consistent in the XML fields, I am not able to display it in a table properly.

Here is the XML:

```
<ItemTaxWithheldList>
    <TaxWithheldComponent>
        <TaxesWithheld>
            <ChargeComponent>
                <ChargeType>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Shipping</ChargeType>
                <ChargeAmount>
                    <CurrencyAmount>-5.54</CurrencyAmount>
                </ChargeAmount>
            </ChargeComponent>
            <ChargeComponent>
                <ChargeType>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Principal</ChargeType>
                <ChargeAmount>
                    <CurrencyAmount>-10.87</CurrencyAmount>
                </ChargeAmount>
            </ChargeComponent>
        </TaxesWithheld>
    </TaxWithheldComponent>
    <TaxWithheldComponent>
        <TaxesWithheld>
            <ChargeComponent>
                <ChargeType>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Other</ChargeType>
                <ChargeAmount>
                    <CurrencyAmount>-0.27</CurrencyAmount>
                </ChargeAmount>
            </ChargeComponent>
            <ChargeComponent>
                <ChargeType>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Shipping</ChargeType>
                <ChargeAmount>
                    <CurrencyAmount>0.0</CurrencyAmount>
                </ChargeAmount>
            </ChargeComponent>
            <ChargeComponent>
                <ChargeType>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Principal</ChargeType>
                <ChargeAmount>
                    <CurrencyAmount>0.0</CurrencyAmount>
                </ChargeAmount>
            </ChargeComponent>
        </TaxesWithheld>
    </TaxWithheldComponent>
    <TaxWithheldComponent>
        <TaxesWithheld>
            <ChargeComponent>
                <ChargeType>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Shipping</ChargeType>
                <ChargeAmount>
                    <CurrencyAmount>0.0</CurrencyAmount>
                </ChargeAmount>
            </ChargeComponent>
            <ChargeComponent>
                <ChargeType>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Principal</ChargeType>
                <ChargeAmount>
                    <CurrencyAmount>-4.87</CurrencyAmount>
                </ChargeAmount>
            </ChargeComponent>
        </TaxesWithheld>
    </TaxWithheldComponent>
</ItemTaxWithheldList>
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Other</th>
    <th>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Shipping</th>
    <th>MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Principal</th>
</tr>
<?php
$response = $xmlFile;

$return_data = simplexml_load_string($response);
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$return_data), TRUE);

foreach ($array['TaxWithheldComponent'] as $itemTaxWithheldList) {
    
echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($itemTaxWithheldList['TaxesWithheld']['ChargeComponent'] as $key) {
        $mpftChargeType = $key['ChargeType'];
        $mpftChargeAmount = number_format((float)$key['ChargeAmount']['CurrencyAmount'], 2, '.', '');

        
        if ($mpftChargeType == 'MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Other') {
            echo '<td>' . $mpftChargeAmount . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>0.00</td>';
        } 
        
        if ($mpftChargeType == 'MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Shipping') {
            echo '<td>' . $mpftChargeAmount . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>0.00</td>';
        }  
        
        if ($mpftChargeType == 'MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Principal') {
            echo '<td>' . $mpftChargeAmount . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>0.00</td>';
        }  

    }

echo '</tr>';

}

?>
</table></body></html>
```

The output is completely wrong as I only need the three columns and rows for each:
[image]

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by storing the charges found in the XML into an array for each item, and then iterating over each of the charge types and outputting the value if it exists or `0.00` otherwise:

```
$chargeTypes = array('MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Other', 'MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Shipping', 'MarketplaceFacilitatorTax-Principal');
foreach ($array['TaxWithheldComponent'] as $itemTaxWithheldList) {
    $charges = array();
    foreach ($itemTaxWithheldList['TaxesWithheld']['ChargeComponent'] as $key) {
        $mpftChargeType = $key['ChargeType'];
        $mpftChargeAmount = number_format((float)$key['ChargeAmount']['CurrencyAmount'], 2, '.', '');
        $charges[$mpftChargeType] = $mpftChargeAmount;
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($chargeTypes as $chargeType) {
        echo '<td>' . ($charges[$chargeType] ?? '0.00') . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
<tr><td>0.00</td><td>-5.54</td><td>-10.87</td></tr>
<tr><td>-0.27</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td><td>-4.87</td></tr>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/e80k5)